# How to filter out the repeat element from JS Array?

Tags: javascript

I have two JS arrays like below:

```
$order = [];
$a = ['about','about','portfolio','contact'];
```

Get the order of items:

```
for($i=0;$i<$a.length;$i++){
    $order.push($i+1);
}
console.log($order);
```

Output: [1,2,3,4]

But I want to filter out the repeat items and got the order like [1,3,4]

Another example

```
$a = array('about','about','about','portfolio','contact','contact');
```

I want to get the order like [1,4,5]

I'm not sure whether I explained clear.
Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store unique values and `Array#map()` to return positions based on `Array#indexOf()`

```js
const arr = ['about', 'about', 'about', 'portfolio', 'contact', 'contact']

const res = [...new Set(arr)].map(v => arr.indexOf(v) + 1)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Can't just use like: `[...new Set(arr)].map((v, index) => index + 1)` ??

Comment: @AshishRanjan no because there are only 3 unique values and that would not return expected result. Set.size===3. Your index is only relative to the new array

Comment: @AshishRanjan used Set simply because it is a painless way to remove duplicates because Set values must be unique and duplicates get ignored

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do the job..

```js
let order = [];
let a = ['about','about','portfolio','contact'];

a.reduce((acc, ele, index) => {
  if (acc.indexOf(ele) === -1) {
    acc.push(ele);
    order.push(index + 1)
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(order)
```

Comment: It works, thank you! But the previous solution is really clear